# Help removing my domain from blacklists

Tags: tls

I bought a domain few days before. but it came to my attention that my domain has been blacklisted by many antivirus programs and search engines as the domain for previously purchased by somebody and he misuse it. Though i have asked few antivirus companies and search engines to review the domain, but i want to know what else i should do to get this thing fixed. Also what type of security certificate should i buy and from where?

please tell me the process in detail for buying a security certificate and best ways to get my domain name removed from blacklisted list.

Comment: Your best bet is to contact the blacklist managers, a certificate won't help at all wrt this issue.

Answer (score 6):

Your best bet for this issue would be to compile a list in Excel that shows all the blacklists that you are on, and begin with identifying if the blacklist requires you to call and confirm the information or if it requires you to register with an account and confirm that it is no longer spamming.

```
| Blacklist Name | Date Identified | How Long before it can show clean | Contact Information |
```

I used to work at an ISP and we had IP addresses for different regions. Thus a large amount of traffic would get blocked because of people getting infected.

I found that for the spamhaus ones it would usually take a few weeks of no one being infected for us to be removed. Symantec and a few others also go off these lists, but it can also help to call and explain your issue. Barracuda is really good about this as well, if you call and inform them of the situation they will generally put in a ticket and 24 hours later you should be off the black lists.

As far as google, you will need to have your site re-indexed if you are showing as a malware site on there.

EDIT:
Here is a list of blacklists, and there delisting policies that should help you well along your way.

SPAMHAUSE - Removal http://www.spamhaus.org/lookup/

Google Malware Removal - https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/168328?hl=en

Barracuda Spam Removal - http://www.barracudacentral.org/rbl/removal-request